# How to change a label text in node module package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm making a react web app, and I have installed a node module package that is in English (react-timelines), but I need to translate a "Today" label text into Spanish to say "Hoy". When I go to the package folder inside `node_module` and change the text then my change doesn't apply to the project.

I have read something about `npm` link that I don't understand very well and I just want to ask if there is a better way to change that simple text only. Could you please recommend me the right approach for simple copy translation?

Answer (score -1):

The contents of node_modules are derived from package.json. That is: package.json describes the libraries/dependencies your application relies on and then, when built using npm, the actual contents of the libraries are downloaded and stored within node_modules. That said, you may not want to manually change contents in node_modules as subsequent npm builds would overwrite your work.

What are you ultimately trying to accomplish/where are you expecting "Hoy" to be displayed from?

Comment: I want to display it [here](https://imgur.com/tWl7Qzc) what should I do in this case? if manually change it, it's not the right option

Comment: Thanks for the pic. You need to find out where that data is supplied from and adjust it accordingly. This could mean modifying the source of react-timelines and packaging locally or narrowing the problem to another module (react-localization?). If you put up a proof-of-concept repo on github I can take a look.